# Synchronize device time for TOTP function

Tags: node.js, steam, steambot

Do you know how I can synchronize my server's time so that TOTP generates right codes at the right time for my steam bot?
Currently using node-steam-totp.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the underlying host in sync with anything? (e.g ntp)

Answer (score 1):

To generate a TOTP code synchronized with the server, you should first use node-steam-totp's [`getTimeOffset()`](https://github.com/DoctorMcKay/node-steam-totp#gettimeoffsetcallback) method. After retrieving the offset, you can go about making your TOTP codes using the optional [`timeOffset`](https://github.com/DoctorMcKay/node-steam-totp#getauthcodesecret-timeoffset) parameter.

Here's an example to get you started:

```
totp.getTimeOffset(function(err, offset, latency) {
    var authcode = totp.getAuthCode(secret, offset);

    //do login stuff
});
```